# File Encoding in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the use of file encoding in android studio? It uses default encoding type:"UTF-8". I am unable to understand that. There are various other encoding techniques also.

How these different encoding types  makes difference?

Comment: you know that data is stored in forms of zeros and ones. when anybody want to retrieve it, he needs to know how to interpret it. should it be a number or string or ... . encoding types are the same. when we reads zeros and ones(binary data) we don't know if it meant to be in Chinese or English, so we use these encoding types to interpret binary to characters in specific language.

Comment: Now I get that.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: you're very welcome.